# how to show a result of 2 different queries in one?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am sorry if the question itself doesn't make much sense but let me explain.

I have 2 tables:  Medicine and Donations

Medicine has:

id_medicine
medicine
quantity

and Donation has:

id_donation
id_medicine
quantity

What i want is a query to show me the total quantity of a medicine available.

I had this query:

```
    SELECT Medicine.name AS 'Medicine', Medicamento.quantity + Donation.quantity AS Quantity 
    FROM Donation 
    INNER JOIN medicine ON donation.cod_medicine = Medicine.cod_medicine 
    ORDER BY 'Medicine'
```

but that only shows the medicine that also has a donation, if the medicine doesn't have a single donation then it doesn't show up. So, again, how can i get the total quantity of every medicine even if it doesn't have a donation? Thank you!

Comment: Is this for a specific flavor of SQL: TSQL, MySQL, Oracle, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

You could you an OUTER JOIN along with a NVL function (assuming it is an Oracle database):

```
SELECT Medicine.name AS 'Medicine', Medicamento.quantity + NVL(Donation.quantity, 0) AS Quantity 
FROM Donation 
LEFT OUTER JOIN medicine ON donation.cod_medicine = Medicine.cod_medicine 
ORDER BY 'Medicine'
```

If it's SQL Server, replace `NVL` with `ISNULL`

The NVL or ISNULL function serves to replace a null value with something else, the second parameter of the function, here it's 0.

Comment: ooh this did work like this:

`SELECT        Medicamento.nombre_Medicamento AS 'Medicamento', Medicamento.fecha_Vencimiento, 
                         Medicamento.cantidad + Donacion_Medicamento.Cantidad AS Cantidad
FROM            Donacion_Medicamento INNER JOIN
                         Medicamento ON Donacion_Medicamento.cod_Medicamento = Medicamento.cod_Medicamento
ORDER BY 'Medicamento'`

(It was microsoft sql but i a little research made it easy to change it) Thank you! I have one question though, do you happen to know how to merge the records that has the same medicine name?

Comment: for example i got this result from the query:

[link](http://puu.sh/cHHTw/08eefe927a.png)

how can i merge the records that has the same name "panadol" and add their quantities?

Comment: you could add a "GROUP BY" followed by the fields you want to group by (so for you all fields, except 'Medicamento' I guess)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT
    Medicine.name AS Medicine
    , Medicine.quantity + COALESCE(Donation.quantity, 0) AS Quantity
FROM Medicine
    LEFT JOIN Donation ON donation.id_medicine = Medicine.id_medicine
ORDER BY Medicine
```